# Using stringr to extract one or multiple words from text string in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(city=c("in London", "in Manchester city", "in Sao Paolo"))
```

I am using str_extract and return the word after 'in' in a separate column.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$city, '(?<=in\\s)\\w+')
```

This works fine for me in 95% of cases. However, there are cases like "Sao Paolo" above where my regex would return "Sao" rather than the city name.

Can someone please help me with amending it to capture either:

1) everything to the end of the text string I am extracting from? OR

2) where there is more than one word after 'in', then return that too

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you just want `(?<=in\\s).+`? Or `(?<=in\\s)\\w+(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)?`? Looks like you would be safer with `(?<=in\\s)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)*`.

Comment: why not just `gsub('^in ', '', df$city)`

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason your regex isn't picking up "Paolo" in "Sao Paolo" is because a space doesn't count as a word character so `\\w+` stops when it gets to the space. You'll want to be careful when tweaking it because if you simply allow spaces, you'll end up capturing "Manchester city" instead of just "Manchester".

Comment: I'd also recommend using `str_match` since you might have double spaces between `in` and the city. E.g. `cities = str_match(df$city, '\\bin\\s+(\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)*)')` and then `cities[,2]` will hold the values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your simplest regex '(?<=in\\s).+' works best in this case. Many thanks!

Comment: Great, posted as an answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all the rest of the string after the first `in` followed with a space, you can use

```
(?<=in\\s).+
```

The lookbehind matches the `in` preposition with a white space after it, but does not return it inside the match since lookbehinds are *zero-width assertions*.

Answer (score 2):

Does this one liner do it for you?

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(c("in London", "in Sao Paulo", "in Manchester City"), "in "), function(x) x[2]))
[1] "London"          "Sao Paulo"       "Manchester City"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(stringr)
df$onlyCity <- str_extract(df$city, '[^in ](.)*')
df
                city        onlyCity
1          in London          London
2 in Manchester city Manchester city
3       in Sao Paolo       Sao Paolo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("^in[ ]*(.*$)", "\\1", df$city)
[1] "London"          "Manchester city" "Sao Paolo"
```

Assumes that your strings start with `"in"`, followed by some number of spaces (won't fail with more than one), followed by the text of interest which is captured from the first non-whitespace character up to the end of the string.